# How to upgrade React Native project after upgrading Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I have [upgraded](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.68.1&to=0.70.2) React Native from version 0.68.1 to version 0.70.2, and react from 17.0.2 to 18.1.0.  That has worked fine, but I have also upgraded Android Studio to version 2021.3.1. I updated configuration files with the React Native CLI, `npx react-native upgrade`. Then I attempted to upgrade the android directory according to the [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.68.1&to=0.70.2) and [manual edits](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) that are necessary to sign an android app. That failed, so I have tried a backup copy but now that fails too despite the fact that the android directory is unchanged from when the app was building correctly. I used Git to revert to a known working copy.

I don't see any procedures to upgrade the Android files after upgrading Android Studio from React Native. Is there any available guidance for the version of Android Studio I use? How can I upgrade the Android project to get it to build with the new version of Android Studio? I'm guessing that Gradle versioning has a lot to do with the errors but I haven't found any explanation or advice to upgrade the project after upgrading Android Studio.

The error I get from PowerShell after running `.\gradlew bundleRelease` is

> Task :app:signReleaseBundle FAILED
> w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)
```

When I open the Android folder in Android Studio I notice errors in `MainApplication.java` and `AsyncStoragePackage.java`: `Cannot resolve symbol 'BuildConfig'`. Invalidating the cache, clean, and rebuild have not changed the results.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found earlier on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33488).  In my instance, there are other messages and the relevant error message is `Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions`.  Simply adding the code to `android/build.gradle` as follows fixed the issue for me.  I expect the version will need to be updated periodically and I'm now sure how to get the version info as my Kotlin REPL will not start.

```
belbuildscript {
    ext {
        // ...
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10' // <- add this line
    }

    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" // <- add this line
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that this sort of problem can be avoided by uninstalling Android Studio before installing a more recent version, and other software may need the same treatment.